# db_merge : Making a query slow

Tags: performance, userpoints

I am using userpoints module to provide points for different actions that they do on my site.

```
mysql> desc userpoints;
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| pid         | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| uid         | int(11) | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| points      | int(11) | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| max_points  | int(11) | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| last_update | int(11) | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| tid         | int(11) | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc userpoints_txn;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| txn_id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| uid           | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| approver_uid  | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| points        | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| time_stamp    | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| changed       | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| status        | tinyint(4)   | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| description   | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| reference     | varchar(128) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| expirydate    | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| expired       | tinyint(4)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| parent_txn_id | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| tid           | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| entity_id     | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| entity_type   | varchar(128) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| operation     | varchar(48)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select count(*) from userpoints;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    24766 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)


mysql> select count(*) from userpoints_txn;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  5784843 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1.04 sec)
```

userpoints_txn takes care of transaction of user points and userpoints table takes care of points for a user.

They are using db_merge to check whether userpoints table has an entry for user and then update if record exists, inserts a new record if it does not exist.  But this query is making things slow.

```
    mysql> SELECT 1 AS expression FROM userpoints userpoints WHERE ( (uid = '10645') AND (tid = '0') ) FOR UPDATE;
+------------+
| expression |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+
1 row in set (![22.13 sec][1])
```

Index details :

[image]

Explain Query

[image]

Any idea on how i can optimize this?

Comment: Run explain on the slow query an post the results here.

Comment: added explain details as well.

Comment: Still doesn't explain the 22 second wait. Try profiling that query http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html